# Problema con funcion pandas.DataFrame.shift

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente dataframe en python:

```
months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
data1 = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200]
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'month' : months,
                    'd1' : data1,
                    'd2' : 0,
                });
```

y requiero recalcular la columna d2, de la siguiente manera:

```
    month    d1      d2
0       1   100   101.0
1       2   200   303.0
2       3   300   606.0
3       4   400  1010.0
4       5   500  1515.0
5       6   600  2121.0
6       7   700  2828.0
7       8   800  3636.0
8       9   900  4545.0
9      10  1000  5555.0
10     11  1100  6666.0
11     12  1200  7878.0
```

lo estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
df['d2'] = (df['d2'].shift(1) + df['d1']) + df['month']
```

pero el resultado no es el esperado:

```
    month    d1      d2
0       1   100     NaN
1       2   200   202.0
2       3   300   303.0
3       4   400   404.0
4       5   500   505.0
5       6   600   606.0
6       7   700   707.0
7       8   800   808.0
8       9   900   909.0
9      10  1000  1010.0
10     11  1100  1111.0
11     12  1200  1212.0
```

no se si soy claro en mi solicitud, agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que cuando haces:

```
df['d2'] = df['d2'].shift(1) + df['d1']
```

Lo que ocurre es que se calcula `df['d2'].shift(1) + df['d1']` lo cual retorna una nueva serie que es reasignada a `df["d2"]` al concluir. Es decir, **la operación no va modificando la columna `d2` a medida que se va realizando, sino que cada nuevo valor generado se usa para crear una nueva `Serie`**.

Esto implica que siempre va a ser `0 + df["d1"]`, ya que inicialmente la columna `d2` solo tiene ceros.

Puedes simplemente usar [`pandas.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
import pandas as pd


months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
data1 = [100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200]
df = pd.DataFrame({
                    'month' : months,
                    'd1' : data1,
                    'd2' : 0,
                });

df['d2'] = df.d1.cumsum()
```

---

> ```
> >>> df
>     month    d1    d2
> 0       1   100   100
> 1       2   200   300
> 2       3   300   600
> 3       4   400  1000
> 4       5   500  1500
> 5       6   600  2100
> 6       7   700  2800
> 7       8   800  3600
> 8       9   900  4500
> 9      10  1000  5500
> 10     11  1100  6600
> 11     12  1200  7800
> ```

### Edición

Si quieres incluir también la columna `month` en la suma acumulada simplemente realiza esta suma previamente a usar el método `cumsum`:

> ```
> >>> df['d2'] = (df.d1 + df.month).cumsum()
> >>> df
>     month    d1    d2
> 0       1   100   101
> 1       2   200   303
> 2       3   300   606
> 3       4   400  1010
> 4       5   500  1515
> 5       6   600  2121
> 6       7   700  2828
> 7       8   800  3636
> 8       9   900  4545
> 9      10  1000  5555
> 10     11  1100  6666
> 11     12  1200  7878
> ```

Comment: podria ayudarme con una nueva respuesta porfavor, acabo de editar la pregunta, gracias

Comment: @YeisonH.Arias mira la edición al final de la respuesta.

Comment: perfecto gracias